# Zend Framework 1 Request remove post

Tags: zend-framework, request

Is there a modifier of request so I can change request method?

I have a two page form and would like to clear the request so that `isPost()` method returns `false`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. 
`isPost()` method return if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` equals `'POST'`.

If I'm not mistaken, there is no way to change `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` with Zend Framework 1.

If you want really change this value, you can do that:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';
```

and `isPost()` will return false.